# How to select multiple library type in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using jQuery in Wordpress. I am trying to display `PDF and Word files` in upload. But I can't do that.
Here is my Code:

```
library: {
type: ['application/pdf']
},
 multiple: true
```

Here I can add **PDF File** only.

I already tried `type: ['application/pdf'],['application/docx']` **AND** `type: ['application/pdf','application/docx']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a jQuery plugin or the `inputElement` it self, if it's a plugin please clarify your code, if it's an `inputElement` you need to set the `accept` attribute like so:

```
$('#myInput').attr('accept', 'application/pdf,application/docx');
```

This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) may help you understand the `accept` attribute.